# Javascript array to point variable name with similar function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, selector

I'm want to shorten this function with array

```
            document.mySchedule.breakfast.onchange = function() {
                var id = document.mySchedule.breakfast.selectedIndex;
                var val = document.mySchedule.breakfast[id].value;
                strUser[0]=val;
            }
            document.mySchedule.lunch.onchange = function() {
                var id = document.mySchedule.lunch.selectedIndex;
                var val = document.mySchedule.lunch[id].value;
                strUser[1]=val;
            }
            document.mySchedule.dinner.onchange = function() {
                var id = document.mySchedule.dinner.selectedIndex;
                var val = document.mySchedule.dinner[id].value;
                strUser[2]=val;
            }
```

I'm try this way but it didn't seem to be work.

```
var selectData = ["breakfast","lunch","dinner"]
for(i = 0; i < selectData.lenght; i++) {
                document.mySchedule.selectData[i].onchange = function() {
                    var id = document.mySchedule.selectData[i].selectedIndex;
                    var val = document.mySchedule.selectData[i][id].value;
                    strUser[i]=val;
                }
            }
```

by the way this use to control selector.
Hope someone can help. thank you

Comment: What "*didn't seem to work*" mean?

Comment: I'm use alert to check data in id and val is undefined look like it didn't know string in selectData[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
var selectData = ["breakfast","lunch","dinner"]
for(i = 0; i < selectData.lenght; i++) {
    var e = document.getElementById(selectData[i]);
    e.onchange = function(){
        strUser[i] = e.value;
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.